# Boosting: In the function gbm() from library gbm and understanding the cv.folds implementation

Tags: r, boosting

In the function gbm() there is a parameter cv.folds. I know this is performing cross-validation but what I don't understand is how to interpret it. I tried extracting it using $cv.error but was greeted with a list of values that seemed to only range from 0.75 to ~0.98.

So what exactly is this parameter doing? If I run this function to boost a classifier, is cv.folds returning cross validation error on each classifier?

Answer (score 2):

This question can be answered by consulting the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/gbm.pdf):

> if `cv.folds < 2` this component is `NULL`. Otherwise, this component is a vector
>   of length equal to the number of fitted trees containing a cross-validated estimate
>   of the loss function for each boosting iteration.

So each of the numbers in your vector is an estimate the loss of a fitted version of your model using one cross validation fold.  To interpret the numbers we would need to know what loss function you were using for your `gbm`.